# Map FAST crawled property powershell

Tags: powershell, fast-search

I want to map people properties in FAST Search: crawled properties to contents hidden using powershell. I know that I can get crawled properties using Get-FASTSearchMetadataCrawledProperty but this list gives me all the ows_crawledproperty. I want user profile crawled properties and map them. Any idea how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FAST cannot index user profiles. You need to configure enterprise search for this.

- Make sure User Profile Synchronization is running and you have profiles imported
- Give your search default content access account "Retrieve People Data for Search Crawlers" permission on User Profile Service Application
- Configure a new Content Source "People" that points to sps3://yourMySiteUrl
- Do a full crawl (this will give you crawled properties in index). User Profile crawled properties are stored in the People category.
- Create managed properties using New-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataManagedProperty cmdlet
- Map crawled and managed properties using New-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataMapping cmdlet
- Do a *full* crawl again

You should now be able to do property restriction keyword queries like

```
yourMappedProperty="something"
```

Comment: I would like to search a user profile property without using the syntax that you mentioned above. (yourMappedProperty="something")

To achive this, I need to change the advanced searchable settings.
I set the Full-Text Index: PeopleIdIx and then it works only giving "something".
What I am trying to find out, how can I set this "PeopleIdx" option of a managed property using PowerShell.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, This is how I have achieved it:

```
$searchapp = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication "FAST4SP2010 QUERY SSA"
 $mp = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataManagedProperty -SearchApplication $searchapp -Identity 'contentshidden'
 $categy = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataCategory -SearchApplication $searchapp -Identity People
  $cats = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataCrawledProperty -SearchApplication $searchapp -Category $categy
   foreach($cat in $cats)
   {

$cp = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataCrawledProperty –name $cat.Name -SearchApplication $searchapp
 New-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataMapping –Managedproperty $mp –crawledproperty $cp -SearchApplication $searchapp
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use Get-FASTSearchMetadataCategory function:

```
$category = Get-FASTSearchMetadataCategory -Name People
$crowledProperties = $category.GetAllCrawledProperties()

$property = //retrive property from $crowledProperties

$managedproperty = New-FASTSearchMetadataManagedProperty -Name webtitle -type 1 -description "description"

New-FASTSearchMetadataCrawledPropertyMapping -ManagedProperty $managedproperty -CrawledProperty $property
```

Comment: Basically, I am using